# Incremental XML generation inheriting root namespace map

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, contextmanager

I'm using LXML's [incremental XML generation](https://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation) to build a large XML file. I need to apply a namespace to some child elements that is defined as part of the root element (`rss` below), but it seems the context manager provided by the incremental XML generation feature doesn't pass the root namespace map to the child nodes. Here is an example:

```
from lxml import etree

FILENAME = "somefile.xml"
NSMAP = {"myns": "http://example.com/"}

with open(FILENAME, "wb") as f:
    # create XML streamer
    with etree.xmlfile(f) as xf:
        # root element
        with xf.element("root", version="1.0", nsmap=NSMAP):
            with xf.element("channel"):
                title = etree.Element("{http://example.com/}title", nsmap=NSMAP)
                title.text = "some text"
                xf.write(title)
```

This yields the following XML file:

```
<root xmlns:myns="http://example.com/" version="1.0">
    <channel>
        <myns:title xmlns:myns="http://example.com/">some text</myns:title>
    </channel>
</root>
```

In the above, the `xmlns:myns` attribute is set twice, both on `root` and on `title`. Ideally, this would be defined only once, on the root node:

```
<root xmlns:myns="http://example.com/" version="1.0">
    <channel>
        <myns:title>some text</myns:title>
    </channel>
</root>
```

Normally when building XML documents you would simply pass the root node to the child with `etree.SubElement`, and so the child element can look up the root namespace map, but in this case the context manager appears to prevent this from happening. Is there a way to achieve this when using incremental XML generation?